# Open pdf file dynamically from toolstripmenu c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, file, pdf, dynamic

i'm trying to open a pdf file from my winform application, while the pdf file is in the directory of the application. I want to pack this app latter so I can open them dynamically even if the app is installed in another machine. I'm using Process.Start(".\file.extension") but I'm getting the error: The system cannot find the file specified. I heard that I need to send it in System32 folder but when I pack it I have no idea how to send it there. Hope you understood and can come with a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pdf file is inside the project itself, You can simply do this:

Your PDF File as seen from the solution explorer > Right Click > Properties
Copy to Output Directory > Copy Always

After this, each time you build your project or when you deploy it, The PDF file will always be included in the project output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
string commandexec = string.format("{0}\{1}",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,filename);

Process.Start(commandexec);
```